# Is there any problem if I use two onMounted() per one component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have only seen examples of one onMounted() per one component.
I'd like to use onMounted() for each feature.
Is there any problem?

MyComponent.vue

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

// Feature A
onMounted(() => {
  // Do something.
});

// Feature B
onMounted(() => {
  // Do something.
});
</script>
```

Comment: To be able to do that is the whole point of Composition API in the first place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that if you plan to extract the features to separate composable functions  :

```html
<script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue';

//fetch data feature
const data = ref([])
onMounted(()=>{
   fetch('someurl').then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => data.value=res.data)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
})


//counter feature
const count=ref();
onMounted(()=>{
  count.value=0
})
</script>
```

then :

```html
<script setup>
...
useFetch();

useCounter();

</script>
```