# Vue3 Composition - how to UnRegister a callback when component unmounts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I've read multiple questions on stackoverflow talking about Vue3's version of `useEffect`, but none of them go explicitly into detail on this question:

Imagine I have a composition component, and I register a callback inside that component that needs to be unregistered when the component no longer exists, or maybe I create a `setInterval` function that needs to have `clearInterval` called on it when the component unmounts. What's the proper pattern to do that?

Should I use `onUnmounted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use `onUnmounted` :

```js
let interval = null;
onMounted(() => {
    interval = setInterval(()=>someFunc, 1000)
})

onUnmounted(() => {
    clearInterval(interval)
})
```

Comment: Can you have multiple `onUnmounted` calls in a single component? And is there any reason necessarily why you'd have to do the `setInterval` inside of `onMounted`, or can you do it outside too?

Comment: Found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001855/is-there-any-problem-if-i-use-two-onmounted-per-one-component

Comment: The code outside the hooks is executed when the component is created (no browser API, no DOM are available), in mounted hook the component is mounted in DOM and it's available to manipulate, in this hook we initialize many stuff, but when the component is unmounted we should run some code to clear any side effects.

Comment: @TKoL It's a good practice to keep SSR-unfriendly async code in onMounted

Comment: @EstusFlask oh interesting, I guess I never really think about that. What makes code SSR-unfriendly?

Comment: @TKoL Asynchronous side effects like setInterval shouldn't run on server side, they can't affect the way it's rendered, just worsen the performance and cause memory leaks